# Curl miss some html elements

Tags: php

```
$curl_handle = curl_init($href);
            curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
            echo $data;
            exit;
```

I'am trying to parse the html page, but as I see there are missing some html elements, but if I go to this url via browser the elements are there, why that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. The server serves different content depending on the detected browser. You can check this by faking the agent of the browser you are using.
2. The additional elements are inserted via JavaScript, which curl can't handle.

Comment: I've checked it , its not javascript, I've tried to emulate browser in curl lib, still can't get those elements...